# PHP overhead vs. ASP.NET

Tags: php, asp.net, performance

I understand that PHP is compiled on the fly.  I was wondering how much of a speed advantage a language like asp.net has on PHP.  How much faster is it?

Comment: PHP is an interpreted language.

Comment: ARe you talking ASP MVC or just straight up webforms

Comment: Faster for what problem? For which developer? On what hardware? I'm pretty sure I can write slow or fast code in either given what I'm trying to do, my skill level, the hardware that I have available.  There's simply no way to give a definitive answer to this.

Comment: Ha.  I just get needled a bit at work for PHP "not being a real language": one supporting fact is the unnecessary overhead.

Comment: You might find this link relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153947/whats-faster-php-vs-asp-vs-jsp-vs-cgi-etc

Comment: Not really. You can use VB or C# as code behind for ASP.NET.

Comment: lol, how vibrant is the VB asp.net community?

Comment: VB.net is quite popular actually, granted I'll pick C# over it any day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you asking because you want to make a choice between the two? Both are very fast, Facebook uses PHP and this site uses ASP.NET, both a extremely quick and scale just fine.

I know its not specifically what you were asking for, but I thought you just might like to know...

Comment: Appreciate it.  I'm a PHP code monkey.  Building small applications for a year now.  I sit across from a C#/.Net MVC guru.  Just looking for some defensive points about PHP if any.

Comment: just yell "Facebook" at him

Comment: Facebook is written in PHP, but it's not "run" in PHP, it's actually translated to C++ via a "translator" called HipHop.  So it's not really accurate to claim that Facebook runs PHP. http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358/

Comment: ready carefully "Facebook uses PHP" not "run" by

Comment: @Mark your distinction between "uses" and "run" is a cop out for a poor answer. Facebook has said many times, publicly, that PHP does not scale for what they do, which is why HipHop was created in the first place.  Furthermore, PHP being compiled into C++ could be analogous to C# or VB being compiled into MSIL, irrespective of the framework of choice, be it ASP.NET, CakePHP, Zend Framework, Lithium, or some homegrown framework.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is slower than ASP.NET because PHP is not compiled, but rather interpreted at run-time.  There is a "compiler" for PHP called HipHop which will translate the PHP to C++ code, then the C++ code can be compiled.  This is what Facebook uses, otherwise PHP is significantly slower at many tasks.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked a million times and a simple google search will return literally thousands of results, many of which will be filled with loads of biased opinions sprinkled with some legitimate objective comparisons.

I think you should start at google and you will surely find the answers you are looking for, as it really depends on the application you are writing and what your goals are for it.

Comment: Oh I assure you I've googled the subject and read some results.  However, one thing you can't do with google: set up a conversation with a plethora of informed programmers and watch the dynamic conversation unfold among them.

Comment: Read some of the blogs that have brought up this very topic and scroll down to the comments section, where you will find exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: To add to my last comment, you could also do a simple search right here on SO to find exactly what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+vs+php